# Google Sheets API v4 Basics

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to get data from google sheets. For example, let's say I have a sheet "test" and I want to get cell a2 from "test", and so I save the contents of cell a2 as a string.

I believe Google Sheets Api v4 (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/sheets/v4) is what I need to use, but I am not sure how to use it.

I have also found similar question posts on stack overflow, but they all seem outdated.

Finally, I have tried this tutorial (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet#step_2_prepare_the_project) with my c# visual studio, but I get error messages (which I can include if it is helpful).

So, **my question** is, how do extract data from a google sheet, using the API or some other tool. Thanks for the help, and please notify me if my question needs editing to better fit this community.

**edit**: So, following the tutorial, I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GoogleSheetsTest1

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        class Program
        {
            static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
            static string ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart";

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                UserCredential credential;

                using (var stream =
                    new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                        System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                    credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes,
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
                }

                // Create Google Sheets API service.
                var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });

                // Define request parameters.
                String spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
                String range = "Class Data!A2:E";
                SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
                        service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

                // Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
                // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
                ValueRange response = request.Execute();
                IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
                if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name, Major");
                    foreach (var row in values)
                    {
                        // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row[0], row[4]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
                }
                Console.Read();


            }

        }
    }
    }
```

The error message I am getting is:
*Error  CS0017  Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.*

I realize this is probably a really stupid question and I hate to be asking for help here, but I am not sure how to use the google api code, so any help/explanation (so I can understand what the fix is) would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: At the moment, your question is extremely broad. It sounds like a more helpful starting point would be "Why can't I get the tutorial to work", telling us exactly what you've tried and what the error messages are. Once you've got that sample code working, you can try to go from there, and ask another specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: you need to read thru https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_overview

Comment: @JonSkeet  I added the code+error messages. I feel silly because I know this is probably an easy fix, but I am not sure what to do here. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Well hang on - the tutorial doesn't use Windows Forms. Have you got *just the tutorial* working? If you're trying to run just the tutorial, you should be creating a console application, not a WinForms application. (It sounds like this code is in Form1.cs and you've got a Program.cs which contains another Main method. That problem has nothing to do with Google Sheets.)

Comment: ok, I'll give that a go. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @JonSkeet  the console worked perfectly. What do I need to change to integrate this into a WPF? (and if you want to put an answer I'll happily accept it as you've done plenty to help already)

Comment: That's far too broad a question, I'm afraid. We don't know what app you're trying to write - but if you've got the sample working, making the same calls from a UI shouldn't be hard. (I'd suggest using async/await to make the threading simpler.)